# SharePoint web app not accessible on server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, alternate-access-mapping, windows-authentication, iis7

I have a simple SharePoint 2013 Foundation set up.  I have configured it with one web app that is accessible on port 80 and added an alternate site mapping and relative binding in IIS.

Central admin is accessible on the server itself, however trying to access the web app, using the local url or the alternate site mapping I get repeated prompts for authenticaiton and then eventually a 401 unauthorised error.

Yet, trying to access the web app from any other pc works fine.  Any ideas how to resolve it?

The server is running Windows 2012 R2 and SQL 2012 R2 with SP2013 Foundation SP1

Comment: Do you try adding the url to trusted zone?

Comment: yeah actually I found the answer shortly after posting this. its to do with disabling the loopbackcheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was to do with the loopback check not being disabled.  To disable I used powershell to set the value to disable it.

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -value "1" -PropertyType dword
```